# How to get contact images from recent call information in Android

Tags: android, join, android-contentprovider

My use case is simple: I want to create a listview similar to the recent call list view in the standard android phone app.

I can query for the recent calls in the android.provider.CallLog.Calls using getContentResolvery().query()...the problem is I also need the contact image, if that contact exists in the users contact list...I believe this would be a join from CallLog.Calls to some other provider, maybe a ContactContract provider?

Ideally I will receive this information in one cursor.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the contact id to get the contatct photo URI. Use the following code for getting photo URI:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;

public Uri getPhotoUri(long contactId) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    try {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+ "="+ contactId+ " AND "+ ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"='"+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+ "'", null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return null; // no photo
        }
        } else {
        return null; // error in cursor process
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
  }
```

Update:

Contact id can be obtained using the phone number

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;

public String fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID },null, null, null);

    String contactId = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return contactId;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no contactID in the CallLog.Calls content provider. I think the only common field between CallLogs.Call and ContactsContract is phone number or name maybe...could we use these fields to adapt your solution?

Comment: you can use the phone number to get the id

Comment: use ContactsContract.PhoneLookup